# 64 bit Wscript AND 64 bit Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0

Tags: ms-access, vbscript, adodb, wsh, dsn

I have 64 bit windows 10 (and 7), 64 bit wscript opening my script, and AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.

I cannot get things to work with everything running x64, though 32 bit wscript works fine. I have attempted this on several computers including a new windows install. I am always greeted with...

> Script:   C:\Users\ARoberts\Desktop\REPORTER\reporter_1.vbs
>   Line: 126
>   Char: 3
>   Error:    Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly
>   installed.
>   Code: 800A0E7A
>   Source:   ADODB.Connection

from the below VBSCRIPT connection method.

```
Set DBConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
With DBConn     
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    '.Properties("Extended Properties").Value = "Excel 12.0 Xml; ReadOnly=false; HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;"
    .Open  fso.BuildPath(CurrentDirectory, "DB.mdb")'xlsx")
End With
```

I have done countless hours of research on this and wonder if the driver simply isn't capable of playing nicely with x64-wscript. I have tried excel files, access databases, along with a preconfigured User DSN. My database is very large and requires a large amount of processing.

Please let me know what other information I can provide and I will update my question with it.

Comment: Google is your friend! https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1d5c04c7-157f-4955-a14b-41d912d50a64/how-to-fix-error-the-microsoftaceoledb120-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine?forum=vstsdb

Comment: I've seen that page before, and nothing there helped get both 64 bit wscript and 64 bit drivers working together. 32 bit works fine again, but due to the amount of processing needed, 64 is required. It is likely just a compatibility thing, they probably never will work together.

Comment: You're sure you are using x64 version of ACE 12? Sounds more like it's not registered in COM for x64. It's likely x86 is installed. Also x86 and x64 ACE 12 do not coexist *(speaking from experience)*. There is no scenario were x64 anything will work fine in x86 so it's more likely x86 is installed and that is what you've been mistakenly using.

Comment: There is at least one way to get both the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of the Access Database Engine ("ACE") installed on the same machine, but it is *not* recommended. That's why the ACE installer bothers to check for the "other" version and aborts if it finds it. If you **really need** the 64-bit version (which is doubtful, quite frankly) then uninstall the 32-bit version, install the 64-bit version, and carry on.

Comment: I have verified that the 32 bit version does not exist on the system. I have looked at the DLL's manually and also checked the available DSN drivers using the ODBC settings window. I am processing millions of records with roughly 1800 columns. I need high precision calculations in many cases too.

Comment: The 64-bit version of ACE definitely does work with 64-bit WSCRIPT.EXE and CSCRIPT.EXE. Test code [here](http://pastebin.com/26Wgp6Kh) works just fine for me on my machine with 64-bit Office 2010 installed.

Comment: Which ODBC Settings window? If it's not `%systemroot%\system32\odbcad32.exe` on a x64 system you're using the wrong ODBC Data Source Administrator. Also verify the existence of the ACE 12 progid in `HKLM\Software\Classes`, there should be a corresponding sub key for `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` in the Windows registry.

Comment: I have been using the 64 bit odbc window.  Also, Gord, I used your script and it checks for the JET dll instead of ACE, I assume that is ok? It said 64.

Comment: The script just checks for the Jet DLL to determine the bit-ness of the environment under which it is running. (Yes, it's OK.)